# ASP.net login module

Tags: asp.net, database, authentication, asp.net-membership

I'm building a website in ASP.net and using a database in mysql. Now I was wondering whether I can export the login module from the Visual Studio environment and export the database into phpmyadmin?

Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering; why would you use MySQL? .NET has an excelent System.Data.SqlClient namespace and works brilliantly out of the box with Microsoft's SQL Server. The Express edition is free to top things off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd run [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) (Located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\), but I'm not sure MySQL is supported at all. Everything in .NET assumes you use Microsoft's SQL Server.

[Edit]

It seems some ppl have made an effort to support MySQL in this scenario :)

[Code Project Project with a MySQL Compliant Membership Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx)

[Lots more](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,63403,63403) [can be found](http://forums.asp.net/t/1661483.aspx/1?MySQL%20Membership%20Provider), so I think it just might work for you :)

Comment: thanks, your link (MySQL compliant membership provider) was really helpful!